# Javascript Show hide

Tags: javascript

I want to make a show and hide my section.

This is working for now.

But I want my section to be hidden when you enter the site, and then when you click it will show. Right now it is the other way around.

How I can fix this?

```
 document.querySelector("#about").addEventListener("click", function   (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}, false);

function showAbout() {
    var myAbout = document.getElementById('about');
    if (myAbout.style.display === 'none') {
        myAbout.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
        myAbout.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap an initialiser in a IIFE or add `display: none` to your element via a default CSS class.

```js
var myAbout = document.getElementById('about');

function showAbout() {
    if (myAbout.style.display === 'none') {
        return myAbout.style.display = 'block';
    }
    return myAbout.style.display = 'none';
}

// Init
(function(){
    myAbout.style.display = 'none';
})();
```

Comment: if i have 4 sections would it then be more efficient if i placed them in an array and then ran it like that instead of repeating my code 4 times?

Answer (score 4):

You could create a css class:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Add this class to your section in html.
And then:

```
document.querySelector("#about")
        .addEventListener("click", function (event) {
           event.preventDefault();
           event.target.classList.toggle('hidden');
        }, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `css` put

```
#about {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I thought about it too, but the toggle won't work correctly the first time, because stylesheet rules aren't added to `.style`: https://jsfiddle.net/yuriy636/mnLpm0t7/

Comment: @nilobarp After running it, and clicking `Toggle` the div shows up?

Comment: Yes, it does indeed.

Comment: @nilobarp Weird, I have to click `Toggle` twice in order to make the div show up. Tested both on Chrome and Firefox latest versions.